# Is $R\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet,R)$ a triangulated functor? What is the opposite of a triangulated category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I'm confused about the relation between signs and duality, or possibly about some essential definitions. Let me present an example of my confusion.
$
\require{AMScd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{{op}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{{Hom}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}
$

Let $R$ be a ring and let $D(R)$ be the derived category of bounded complexes of $R$-modules. How is $D(R)^{\op}$ triangulated? All the sources I've found use this definition:

> If $K$ is a triangulated category, then $K^{\op}$ is  canonically a triangulated category by making $A^{\op}[1]:= (A[-1])^{\op}$ and saying that a triangle is distinguished iff its opposite is distinguished.

It seems to me that with this definition $R\Hom(\bullet,R)$ cannot be an exact functor. Consider the following example, with $R = \mathbb Z$. Consider the following distinguished triangle, where the columns represent complexes, and the bottom row sits in degree $0$:
\begin{CD}
(1) @. 0 @>{}>> 0 @>{}>> \Z @>{\epsilon_2}>> \Z\\
@. @VVV @VVV @V{\epsilon_13}VV @VVV \\
@. \Z @>{3}>> \Z @>{1}>> \Z @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
The signs $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in \{\pm 1\}$ depend on your convention. For example, if you go by the Stacks Project or http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/papers/signs.pdf , $\epsilon_1=\eps_2=1$. Suppose that the triangle resulting from applying $R\Hom(\bullet,\Z)$ was distinguished, i.e. the following triangle, where now the top row is in degree $0$:
$$
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> \Z @>{1}>> \Z @>{3}>> \Z\\
@VVV @V{\epsilon_13}VV @VVV @VVV \\
\Z @>{\eps_2}>> \Z @>>> 0 @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$
By applying axiom TR2 twice to the triangle (1), we can see that this triangle is also distinguished. It also has the top row sitting in degree $0$.
$$
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> \Z @>{-\eps_2}>> \Z @>{3}>> \Z\\
@VVV @V{-\epsilon_13}VV @VVV @VVV \\
\Z @>{-1}>> \Z @>>> 0 @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$
Now we apply TR3. Let $C_n$ be the complex $\Z\overset{n}\to\Z$. If the above two triangles are distinguished, then there must be a map filling this diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
(2) @. \Z[-1] @>{\eps_2}>> C_{\eps_13} @>{1}>> \Z @>{3}>> \Z\\
@. @V{1}VV @V{\alpha}VV @V{\exists?}VV @V{1}VV \\
@. \Z[-1] @>{-1}>> C_{-\eps_13} @>{-\eps_2}>> \Z @>{3}>> \Z.
\end{CD}
$$
Here $\alpha$ is the map
$$
\begin{CD}
\Z @>{\eps_13}>> \Z\\
@V{\eps_2}VV @V{-\eps_2}VV  \\
\Z @>{-\eps_13}>>  \Z.
\end{CD}
$$
There is no arrow filling diagram (2): the right hand square forces it to be $1$, and the left hand square forces it to be $-1$.

Where am I going wrong? If the definitions need to change, what is the (a?) most reasonable convention to take?

This question is related: [$D$ is triangulated. Then opposite functor $op:D\to D^{op}$ 's image is triangulated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579165/d-is-triangulated-then-opposite-functor-opd-to-dop-s-image-is-triangul) . This might also be related: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08I0 .